# How to fix random erroneous behaviour of application windows when using compiz?

Tags: compiz

I am not sure whether you have faced this. Since we have switched to compiz as the window manager, the application windows show the following erratic behaviour at irregular basis  for both of my machines (different brands, different monitors, both running regularly upgraded versions of Ubuntu),

1. The windows once minimized and then maximized, move from one workspace to another.
2. Sometimes I loose a window, it can not be found in any of the workspaces. I have searched each and everyone of them.
3. Some application windows, once minimized and them maximized, change in size, mostly becoming larger.
4. Sometimes, when I try to move one window from one workspace to another using built-in workspace switcher, by click and drag, the window will go to all the workspaces except one random one.

At first I thought that the workspace switcher (not built-in) was to blame. Previously, I used docky, now I use Avant Window Navigator, without any appreciable improvement in this regard.

The problem is, the problem is regenerateable, but only on a random basis.

I use 2 X 4 (R X C) workspaces.

Hope somebody can suggest me something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Compiz Config Settings Manager (CCSM) and try to fix this behavior.

If you haven't installed , install it from Ubuntu-Software-Center. Search for: compizconfig.

You can call it from Dash writing : compizconfig

Although this program is dangerous and needs to be careful when you use it , will allow you to fix such behaviors.

Following is an example that may fix your problem.

[image: ccsm - Window Management]

Change the algorithm to smart (or any other that meet your needs)

[image: ccsm - Window Management - General]

Thanks

Comment: I installed compizconfig-settings-manager

Comment: But after installation and invocation of ccsm, I find that my launcher no longer appears. Any conflict?

I uninstalled compizconfig-settings-manager.

Comment: Does compizconfig-settings-manager have any conflict with myunity?

Comment: compizconfig-settings-manager is just a front-end of compiz compositing manger. A gui application that allows you to manage multiple plugins. It has nothing to do with your problem of launcher etc (IF you don't change something). Install it again and see if Unity plugin is enabled.

Comment: I have tried the things the way you indicated and at the first impression, everything is looking all right and (primary impression), improved.
I will let you know the final results after a couple of days.
I don't know what happened last time. I am not exactly a newbie.

Comment: No, things are not all right. An okular window running in Workspace 2, has suddenly appeared in Workspace 1 after a few window switching (emacs-terminal-okular). Looks like I need to give up the issue.

Comment: You can try something else. From the same window that I show to you in the answer, goto "Fixed Window Placement" and set a specific window(program) to open to a specific workspace. You can use "Grab" for automatically fill of "Window Class". If you want further help , tell me to upload a picture. Thanks

Comment: I would appreciate uploading a picture. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I have already tried it, but there too many new concepts to accommodate to my current schedule. Thanks.